# in nodejs access variable outside callback like gloabal varaible

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
    var coll= '';
    function test(callback){
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
          if(err) throw err;
          coll=db
          callback(coll);
        });
    }

    test();
    console.log(coll)
```

This is my code. When i print 'coll' variable it says undefined. How to access a variable from the outside of callback. Currently getting error callback is not a function

Comment: coll=db; try this

Comment: already done that inside MongoClient.connect function .

Comment: the callback is asynchronous you put `console.log(coll);` inside a callback function. you can not call the variable `coll` outside the function because it will only be defined after the `MongoClient.connect` callback since it is asynchronous. thats why `console.log(coll)` outputs empty|undefined|null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **not passing** any callback function as argument to your `test()` function, therefore the statement in your `test()` function: `callback(coll)`, will throw an error ending your script prior to calling `console.log(coll)`.

Comment: should it be like test(function(coll) { console.log(coll)  }  )

Comment: @ABC It depends. What do you want to do with the callback function?

Comment: i want to make coll variable global . so that i can access database object outside MongoClient.connect function .  how can we do this ? Please help

Comment: Just try first removing the callback. Let me know about the results.

Comment: thanks it worked like this var coll= '';
function test(callback){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) 
    {
      if(err) throw err;
      callback(db);
    });
}

test(function(result){
  coll = result;
});                                                                                                                                          console.log(coll)                                                                                                but coll is undefined outside test() . can't we access it like global variable  outside callback ?